# ASP.NET app hosted in godaddy & somee. App is working fine in somee. But in godaddy, all page redirections is giving 302 status code often

Tags: asp.net, godaddy-api

I have hosted an ASP.NET app both in GoDaddy and Somee. In Somee everything is working fine.

But in GoDaddy, whenever a user clicks on any hyperlink the page redirection button's requested page is not loaded. Instead it is redirected to a login page with 302 status code. There is no exception occurring and the URL is also correct. When I traced the request, I found that the page load method begins but it is not getting ended.

Please let me know if I have to make any changes to the configuration or the settings.

Comment: not a lot to go on. If in place of clicking on a hyper link, what happens when you type in the URL directly to those links - do they work? As noted, we don't have much to go on here. Are the hyper links just links, or do they have code behind for the re-direction to a different page? As noted, try typing in the URL into the browser - see if that works. So, you have to provide more details here.

Comment: I have tried using code behind for redirection and direct url also but issue  not resolved. In page load below code is present                                                                       if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || ActiveUser == null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Session.Abandon();
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", true);
            }

Comment: but what about typing in a given URL by hand - do they work? I mean, if typing in general URLs don't work, then of course some hyper link not going to work, right? I mean do pages and code run in general, or does just "some" hyper links don't work? As I stated, if a hyper link does not work, what happens when you type in the URL direct by hand then? If they don't work, then the sites not at all working and you have a FAR GREATER problem then just some hyper link not working then, right?